# JavaScript ES6 Classes - Is it an anti-pattern to call a static method to setup an instance within a class?

Tags: javascript, class, static-methods, es6-class, instance-methods

I'm creating a class that calls a method to do some processing and setup some data. I'm using ESLINT and it is warning me that I shouldn't use `_` in front of a method that doesn't reference `this` within. This method is only meant to be used within the instance. Turning the method into a static method removes the warning. Was wondering if it is an anti-pattern to using static methods to setup an instance during instantiation or should it be kept as an instance method? Example class below. Thanks!

```
class AppDataArray extends BaseXmlBuilder {
  constructor(arrayOfData) {
    super();
    this.payload = this._buildAppDataArray(arrayOfData);
  }

  static _buildAppDataArray(arrayOfData) {
    const arrayOfAppData = arrayOfData.map((data) => {
      const { app, name, value } = data;
      const appData = new AppData(app, name, value);
      return appData.payload;
    });
    return arrayOfAppData;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems fine to me. If you have access to the [feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields), make the method private.

Comment: "*ESLINT is warning me that I shouldn't use `_` in front of a method that doesn't reference this within.*" - are you sure this has to do with the `_` prefix? Really this is true for any method, if it doesn't use `this`, it should be `static`, whatever the name.

Comment: Why not just turn it into a factory method? Give it the array, it does whatever it needs, then it initialises the object with the result.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on your case. Do you want to use this method very often both inside and outside the class ? It so then keeping it static is fine. But if you don't need this method outside class without wanting to make its object then convert it into normal member method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).